# Difference between osrm route and match service

Tags: osrm

What is the difference between OSRM route service and match service?

Answer (score 10):

According to [OSRM documentation](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/master/docs/http.md), route and match are 2 endpoints with different objectives:

- [Route](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.5.1/api/#route-service): It will return the fastest route between the coordinated in the supplied order. For example:

  `https://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/-77.0969009399414,38.89397221118197;-77.08866119384766,38.88154580068335;-77.0745849609375,38.88515369217454;-77.05432891845703,38.90586211685612?overview=false&alternatives=true&steps=true`

  A call to this endpoint will return the shortest path from `lat: -77.0969009399414, lon: 38.89397221118197` to `lat -77.08866119384766, lon: 38.88154580068335` and then to `lat: -77.05432891845703, lon: 38.90586211685612`
- [Match](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.5.1/api/#match-service): This endpoint works in a complete different way. Given a GPS dataset, the match service will try to match those points to the road network in the most pausible way.

So, if you have *few GPS points* and want to get the *best route* to visit them, you will use the **route** service. If you have a *lot of GPS points* and want to *re-construct the most probable followed path*, you will use the **match** service