# How to use OSRM's match service

Tags: osrm

As stated in the header: how can I use the match call?
I tried

```
http://router.project-osrm.org/match/v1/driving/8.610048,46.99917;8.530232,47.051?overview=full&radiuses=49;49
```

I am not sure, whether the list of `radiuses` is given correctly.
I can't get it work. I also tried `[49;49]` or `{49;49}` The command works with `route`:

```
http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/8.610048,46.99917;8.530232,47.051?overview=full
```

For backround see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50697702/5784831)

**Edit**: If you look at the example [here](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.5.1/api/#match-service), itr seems, the `timestamps` are not needed `/match/v1/{profile}/{coordinates}?steps={true|false}&geometries={polyline|polyline6|geojson}&overview={simplified|full|false}&annotations={true|false}`

Comment: I think `match` only works when you have associated timestamps. It's used to match a GPS trace against the network and work out what your most plausible path was.

Comment: @Phylogenesis Good point, but if you look at the solution suggest [here](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/issues/3464) it seems this should work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.5.1/api/#match-service):

> Large jumps in the timestamps (> 60s) or improbable transitions lead to trace splits if a complete matching could not be found.

I think that's the problem with your request. The two given points are more than 60s appart and OSRM cannot match them successfully. The `radiuses` are specified correctly.

The following query works for me:

```
http://router.project-osrm.org/match/v1/driving/8.610048,46.99917;8.620048,46.99917?overview=full&radiuses=49;49
```

This returns:

```
{"tracepoints":[{"location":[8.610971,46.998963],"name":"Alte Kantonstrasse","hint":"GKUFgJEhBwAAAAAAHQAAAAAAAAC5AAAAAAAAAB0AAAAAAAAAuQAAAPsCAACbZIMAsyXNAgBhgwCCJs0CAAAPABki8hY=","matchings_index":0,"waypoint_index":0,"alternatives_count":0},{"location":[8.620295,46.999681],"name":"Schönenbuchstrasse","hint":"nIEFAJ7IFIA3AAAAZAAAAAAAAADYAAAANwAAAGQAAAAAAAAA2AAAAPsCAAAHiYMAgSjNAhCIgwCCJs0CAAAPABki8hY=","matchings_index":0,"waypoint_index":1,"alternatives_count":5}],"matchings":[{"distance":922.3,"duration":114.1,"weight":114.1,"weight_name":"routability","geometry":"onz}Gqyps@Wg@S_@aCaFMUYo@c@w@OKOCWmAWs@aBiDsAsCMYH[HY\\_@h@ObBW^w@BQAUKu@ASF[ZaABOFYpAyIf@mD","confidence":0.000982,"legs":[{"distance":922.3,"duration":114.1,"weight":114.1,"summary":"","steps":[]}]}],"code":"Ok"}
```

So the two given input points `8.610048,46.99917` and `8.620048,46.99917` are matched to `8.610971,46.998963` and `8.620295,46.999681`.

So as far as I can see, if you want to implement something like [that](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/issues/3464), you need to give OSRM more input points on its way which are less than 60s apart.

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43383783/difference-between-osrm-route-and-match-service/43890717#43890717) for an explanation about the differences between `route` and `match` service.

Answer (score 1):

Here [a jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/afarber/dfszt8ng/) for you, showing how to use OSRM map matching service.

Click 5 times at the map and the map matched route will be drawn in red color:

[image: Animated OpenStreetMap]

Below is the copy of my Javascript code (license: public domain):

```js
'use strict';

function processOsrmReply(data) {

  console.log('Received OSRM map matching reply:');
  console.log(data);

  for (var i = 0; i < data.matchings.length; i++) {
    var matching = data.matchings[i];
    var coordinates = matching.geometry.coordinates;
    var latLngs = coordinates.map(coordinate => [coordinate[1], coordinate[0]]);
    L.polyline(latLngs, { color: 'red' }).addTo(linesGroup);
  }
}

function sendOsrmRequest(lngLats) {
  // create an array of radiuses, same length as lngLats array
  var radiuses = lngLats.map(lngLat => 49);

  var url = 'https://router.project-osrm.org/match/v1/driving/' +
    lngLats.join(';') +
    '?overview=simplified' +
    '&radiuses=' +
    radiuses.join(';') +
    '&generate_hints=false' +
    '&skip_waypoints=true' +
    '&gaps=ignore' +
    '&geometries=geojson';

  console.log('Sending OSRM map matching query to the URL ' + url);

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.onload = function() {
    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
      var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
      processOsrmReply(data);
    } else {
      console.log('Error: ' + this.status);
      // remove polylines and markers
      linesGroup.clearLayers();
      markersGroup.clearLayers();
    }
  };
  request.send();
}

function processMapClick(ev) {
  // get the count of currently displayed markers
  var markersCount = markersGroup.getLayers().length;
  if (markersCount < MARKERS_MAX) {
    L.marker(ev.latlng).addTo(markersGroup);
    // remove polylines
    linesGroup.clearLayers();
    // connect all markers in the markersGroup by a blue polyline
    var latLngs = markersGroup.getLayers().map(marker => marker.getLatLng());
    L.polyline(latLngs, { color: 'blue' }).addTo(linesGroup);
    return;
  }

  // get the count of currently displayed polylines
  var linesCount = linesGroup.getLayers().length;
  if (linesCount > 1) {
    // remove polylines and markers
    linesGroup.clearLayers();
    markersGroup.clearLayers();
    return;
  }

  // create an array of string: "lng,lat" with 6 digits after comma
  var lngLats = markersGroup.getLayers().map(marker =>
    parseFloat(marker.getLatLng().lng).toFixed(6) + ',' +
    parseFloat(marker.getLatLng().lat).toFixed(6)
  );

  sendOsrmRequest(lngLats);
}

var MARKERS_MAX = 4;
var startPosition = [51.4661, 7.2491];
var map = L.map('map').setView(startPosition, 14).on('click', processMapClick);
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

// layer groups for markers and polylines
var markersGroup = L.layerGroup();
map.addLayer(markersGroup);
var linesGroup = L.layerGroup();
map.addLayer(linesGroup);
```

```css
html, body { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#status {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1/dist/leaflet.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1/dist/leaflet-src.min.js"></script>

<div id="status">Click 5x at the map to send OSRM map matching request</div>
<div id="map"></div>
```